# execute function sequentitaly angular 4 / typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, asynchronous, promise, synchronization

```
    onRefresh() {
        let self = this;
        self.clearRoute()
        self.refresh.emit();
    };
```

Clear Route function

```
    clearRoute() {
        let self = this;
            var currentUrl = self._router.url;
            if (currentUrl.indexOf("?") != -1) {
                self._router.navigate([]);
            }
        });
    }
```

** I USED PROMISE AND OBSERVABLE AND SUBSCRIBE BUT NOT WORKING FOR ME **

Comment: Can you describe in detail what is expected and what is not working? May be, create a stackblitz as well.

Comment: self._router.navigate([]) <-  because of authentication it is showing please wait after this is completed then the spinner moves ....but here second function which is emit moves in background..->as I am Doing refresh loading the data->After emit ->loadData(name,offset = 0,field,value) so here agn spinner moves

Comment: means spinner in background plus (authenticate please wait pop up + spinner---------this is der to take me to first page )

Comment: any question ? --- i  have put a simple question -> self.clearRoute() then  self.refresh.emit(); But i noticed promise and observable not working maybe bcoz it is an api hit ...

Comment: Which one is the API? What is `_router`? What I meant was to edit the question and provide more details. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask